# If I try to clear dynamically added tabs using clear_widgets function I get an error(mdtabs can remove only subclass of MDTabslabel or MDTabsBase

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBasefrom kivy.lang import Builder from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView

from kivymd.app import MDApp from kivymd.uix.tab import MDTabsBase

KV = MDBoxLayout: orientation: "vertical"

```
MDToolbar:
    title: "Example Tabs"

MDTabs:
    id: tabs
```

```
MDList:

    MDBoxLayout:
        adaptive_height: True

        MDFlatButton:
            text: "ADD TAB"
            on_release: app.add_tab()

        MDFlatButton:
            text: "REMOVE LAST TAB"
            on_release: app.remove_tab()

        MDFlatButton:
            text: "GET TAB LIST"
            on_release: app.get_tab_list()
```

class Tab(ScrollView, MDTabsBase):
Pass

class Example(MDApp):
index = 0

```
def build(self):
    return Builder.load_string(KV)

def on_start(self):
    self.add_tab()

def get_tab_list(self):
    pass

    print(self.root.ids.tabs.get_tab_list())

def add_tab(self):
    self.index += 1
    self.root.ids.tabs.add_widget(Tab(text=f"{self.index} tab"))

def remove_tab(self):
    if self.index > 1:
        self.index -= 1
    self.root.ids.tabs.clear_widgets()
```

Example().run()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, that is a bug in the `MDTabs` code. The `MDTabs` widget has a structure that includes an `MDTabBar` as a child of the `MDTabs`. The `clear_widgets()` code tries to remove that `MDTabBar`, but the `MDTabs` code will always raise an `Exception` when you try to remove that `MDTabBar`. When you use `add_widget()` on the `MDTabs`, the newly added widget gets added to a `MDGridLayout` inside that `MDTabBar`, so you can use `clear_widgets()` on that `MDGridLayout` instead of on the entire `MDTabs`. Here is a modified version of your `remove_tab()` method that uses that approach:

```
def remove_tab(self):
    if self.index > 1:
        self.index -= 1
    self.root.ids.tabs.ids.layout.clear_widgets()
```

Comment: It works perfectly thanks I almost took a detour by using tabbed panel but you just saved me that time thanks a lot